# Is there any way to debug "debug symbol disabled" executable through remote debugging with GDB?

Tags: linux, gdb

Is there any way to debug "debug symbol disabled" executable through remote debugging with GDB ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example, I have a program on an ARM based target and fully stripped and no debug symbols are enabled. Is there a way to debug this program remotely without recompiling. There might be some ways to load the debug symbols enabled binary locally on the host machine and do the remote debugging. **Would be really helpful if somebody knows those commands and comment it here**